# Can I enlarge OS C: drive of my Windows 8 PC?

Tags: windows, windows-8, partitioning

Last year I got a new Western Digital WD Blue 500GB HDD to replace my old drive. The first thing I did was to install latest Windows 8. While installing Windows 8 I created 3 partitions, C drive for the OS and others for storage. The OS partition is 120GB (which at the time I thought would be plenty big) but I'm now realizing its too small! I wonder if it's possible to re-size HDD partition without reformatting and re-install my Windows 8. So that is my question, Can i enlarge os c drive of my windows 8 without having to re-format?

I've used the Norton Partition Magic and Disk Management to make this happen but there doesn't seem to be any options to make it happen. Thanks for any help you guys can give regarding my question. I've worked hard to optimize my current install of Windows 8 and would hate to start all over again.

Comment: Windows Disk Management can do this if there is disk space available. I highly recommend against using anything with "Norton" branding. Even if you had to reformat (which you don't) the tools (dism) in Windows setup would allow you to image the drive and write the image to the reformatted drive.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done. First defragmment the partitions for best results. Then use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net) to shrink the data partition adjacent to the OS partition, and enlarge the OS partition accordingly so no unallocated space is left.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to delete any adjacent partitions, then extend your partition to that unallocated space with Disk Management.

Comment: Delete isn't needed. One can shrink adjacent drive.